# SCREAM: Error suppresion ignored for Parse error: syntax error PHP

Tags: php, mysql

hi im learning PHP and i start with a CRUD System, i install a WAMP server on Windows and when i run it I get the following error message.

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for. Parse error: syntax error,
>   unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\futbol\registro_usuarios.php on line 10

This is my code

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if(!$db_server) die ("Unable to connect to MySQL:" . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select the database: " . mysql_error());

query = "INSERT INTO registro (nombre, apellido, correo) VALUES('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]', '$_POST[email]')";

echo "Usuario registrado";

mysql_close($db_server);
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to add a `$` in front of `query`. PHP expects its variables to start with that. I guess hence the parser error, since it probably expected a function call and was confused by the equals sign. Please also take a look at 'SQL code injection'. Your SQL query has an injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO registro (nombre, apellido, correo) VALUES('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]', '$_POST[email]')";
```

`query` should be `$query`, there you are declaring a variable.